# ion-item onclick show deteil info in another div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, onclick

I am now trying to use ionic to build my website. I have constructed my ion-list with ion-item ng-repeat to fetch the data array from my JavaScript file. And I would like to make it clickable and the item's detail information can be shown on the right side of my webpage.
When items are not clicked, the right side should be blank.
Please refer to the following illustration:
[image]

I have found an example similar to what I want to do, but I would like to make them in a same page. Any suggestion or directions? thanks!!

> example credits to Krishna Gopinath: http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/52Haa/

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="prof-list" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ion-list` by default occupies the full width in mobile view. So, you need to replace the defaults but changing defaults is not a good solution. Either you need to create your own named views by angular or you need to follow ionic defaults, that is your wish. If you wish to do as your requirement in the question, create two `div` elements in the view side by side.

```
<body>
 <div ui-view="list">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item></ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </div>
 <div ui-view="details"></div>
</body>
```

So, in `list` view, display your list and hide the `details` view by default. When you click on the list item show `details` view. May be this is good for browsers.

You need to use angular's `ui-router` to configuring states. Set same state for clicking on `list-item`. Changing the default behavior leads to spent more time. Mobile size configuration are not good for this. You also can do this by ionic side navigation menu if you are interested

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Probably it will be the best way to do so... but it is still struggling for displaying data according to the item selected... thank you so much anyway!:)