# Get info of the clicked ion-items

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

[Previous Question I raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177189/ion-item-onclick-show-deteil-info-in-another-div/41177720#41177720)

Hi, above is a question i asked in stack overflow. As a follow-up of that questions, if I am trying to use the ui-view to identify the lists and details.
How can I track which ion-item I have clicked / currently active in order to show the relevant detail on the right side?

Please give me some suggestions and directions about that! I have already struggling with the same page for a week... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

```
  <ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click=clickedItem(item)>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Now in controller

```
$scope.clickedItem = function(item){
   //do stuff here
}
```

You can do this by `$index` like,

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click=clickedItem($index)>
```

But It is not godd solution because, If we sort list or search items list, the index value will be changed. So, pass the item to the function.